# Getting indexes of maximum number in array

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

I have an array containing numbers which are ranks.

Something like this :

**0 4 2 0 1 0 4 2 0 4 0 2**

Here `0` corresponds to the lowest rank and `max` number corresponds to highest rank. There may be multiple indexes containing highest rank.

I want to find index of all those highest rank in array. I have achieved with following code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Index{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] data = {0,4,2,0,1,0,4,2,0,4,0,2};
        int max = Arrays.stream(data).max().getAsInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
            if(data[i]==max){
               indexes.add(i);
            }
        }

        for(int j=0;j<indexes.size();j++){
            System.out.print(indexes.get(j)+" ");   
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I have got result as : **1 6 9**

Is there any better way than this ?

Because, In my case there may be an array containing millions of elements due to which I have some issue regarding performance.

So,

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Streaming a some overhead, so replace that stream line with a regular `for` loop, to find the max value, may improve performance a bit. Otherwise, probably not, but why don't you profile the code and see if anything pops out?

Comment: Your problem is that you're iterating over the array twice - once to find what the maximum value is, and then once to find all the instances of it.  You really only need to iterate over the array once.

Comment: This is the sample case. I've got array from a function that can have variable size usually large and this is part of whole execution and I want to improve

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One approach would be to simply make a single pass along the array and keep track of all indices of the highest number.  If the current entry be less than the highest number seen so far, then no-op.  If the current entry be the same as the highest number seen, then add that index.  Otherwise, we have seen a new highest number and we should throw out our old list of highest numbers and start a new one.

```
int[] data = {0,4,2,0,1,0,4,2,0,4,0,2};
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i=0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    if (data[i] == max) {
        vals.add(i);
    }
    else if (data[i] > max) {
        vals.clear();
        vals.add(i);
        max = data[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I would have proposed, you were just a bit quicker! That is the fastest you can get, one pass over the entire array and you are done.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution.  I think the question is a duplicate, and this was the correct answer last time too.

Comment: This will waste some time building up index values from max-so-far values, until the first instance of max value is found. Since that includes boxing the indexes, it's not entirely cheap, and a `for` loop is very fast, so is iterating twice more costly than building up and throwing away bad indexes? Only profiling can tell. But using `HashSet` is definitely worse than using `ArrayList`, since there will never be duplicate index values collected.

Comment: will it be more efficiently if you try to pick elements from both head and rear in one loop?

Comment: Why the `HashSet`? Indexes that are added to the index collection are always distinct. So a simple `ArrayList` should perform better,

Comment: @Andreas I have been waiting for a comment from you, much as a dog awaits for a bone from his master.  I switched to use a list instead of a set.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks a lot , I have tried your answer and works. It gives result quite faster.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the Stream- way... I would suggest you to stay there :)

```
int[] data = { 0, 4, 2, 0, -1, 0, 4, 2, 0, 4, 0, 2 };
int max = Arrays.stream(data).max().getAsInt();
int[] indices = IntStream.range(0, data.length).filter(i -> data[i] == max).toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

As i see your program goes through the array 2 times.You can try this:
Run through the array finding the max of this array.When you find a max just save every other element that is equal to the current max and their values.This way you only go through the array only once.
Here is an example: Let's say you have the following array {1,3,5,3,4,5} and you go through it.You will first save the 1 as max then the 3 then the 5 which is the max of this array.After saving 5 you won't save 3 or 4 but you will save 5 as it is equal to the max.Hope i helped.

Comment: This is what [answer by Tim Biegeleisen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44084017/5221149) does.

Comment: I know but i posted it almost the same exact time.I guess the time it got me to finish it he already posted it.