# Finding all numbers in a array with top frequency?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find out all the numbers with maximum frequency. i.e If maximum frequency is 5 then, I need all numbers that occurred 5 times in a array.

let us consider following example of array:

**1 8 7 8 9 2 1 9 6 4 3 5**

Here, Most frequent numbers are 8, 1, 9 with highest frequency of 2. My expected output is something like this:

```
8 => 2
1 => 2
9 => 2
```

In my project, I am trying to find out most frequent numbers and least frequent numbers. Here I want just most frequent numbers.

I have generated 1000 random numbers similar to my project scenario and have calculated distinct numbers and then their occurrence.

```
    int n=100;
    int N=1000;

    int data[] = new int[N];
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    Random random = new Random();

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        int  number = random.nextInt(n);
        data[i] = number;
        set.add(number);
    }

    int frequency[] = new int[set.size()];
    Integer[] distinct = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);

    for (int j=0;j<set.size();j++){
        int count=0;
        for(int k=0;k<N;k++){
            if(distinct[j]==data[k]){
                count = count+1;
            }
        }
        frequency[j] = count;
    }
```

After calculating frequencies of each number, I have calculated numbers with most frequencies using answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44083935/getting-indexes-of-maximum-number-in-array) which is optimized one.

```
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int q=0; q < frequency.length; ++q) {

        if (frequency[q] == max) {
            vals.add(q);
        }

        else if (frequency[q] > max) {
            vals.clear();
            vals.add(q);
            max = frequency[q];
        }
    }

    for(int num : vals){
        System.out.println(distinct[num]+" => "+frequency[num]);
    }
```

Here, Loop in first code making whole process slower. This is only part of large code and sample test case.

I want to make the process faster since there may be large elements in the array in real case.

Anyone have way to optimize those loops ?
 or 
some other way to get the result ?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: can you try working with my code that I've answered below. Should be alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help you . a perfectly optimised code and guess what ? It works in O(N) .

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = { 1, 8, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i : A) {
        if (map.containsKey(i)) {
            map.put(i, map.get(i) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(i, 1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sortByValue(map));
    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<Integer>(sortByValue(map).keySet());
    int maximumPossibleFrequency = map.get(keys.get(keys.size() - 1));
    for (int i = keys.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (map.get(keys.get(i)) < maximumPossibleFrequency) {
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println(keys.get(i) + " => " + map.get(keys.get(i)));
        }
    }
}

public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> unsortMap) {

    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(unsortMap.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
            return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    });

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list) {
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return result;

}
}
```

Comment: nice performance for the large size array as well. Can you explain about logic and flow of above code ?

Comment: @Sagar well as you can see, this method, sortByValue, is used to sort the map on the basis of it's value, and mind it, I was scanning the map from bottom to top keeping the higher frequency to lower frequency order in my mind. Again the temporary variable maximumPossibleFrequency is assigned with the highest possible frequency from the map and now I believe you can figure out the rest by yourself :) btw if you feel like this solved your problem, please mark it as accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: @tucuxi yes your reason makes sense, agreed. But "object" is a bit strong word , you can contradict in a nicer way I believe. Cheers

Comment: @murasing - I see you have fixed the code, so I have removed the comment. Not because of wording, since it was not meant to be offensive; it is the nicest way I could find to point out something that could be improved -- but because the problem is now fixed, which is good for the answer. Congrats on getting it accepted!

Answer (score 5):

I would use streams for this. It doens’t turn out to be very much shorter, but once you get comfortable with streams, it will be conceptually simpler.

```
    Map<Integer, Long> frequencies = Arrays.stream(data)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));
    if (frequencies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No data");
    } else {
        long topFrequency = frequencies.values()
                .stream()
                .max(Long::compareTo)
                .get();
        int[] topNumbers = frequencies.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() == topFrequency)
                .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .toArray();
        for (int number : topNumbers) {
            System.out.println("" + number + " => " + topFrequency);
        }
    }
```

With the example data from the question it prints the desired (only in another unpredictable order):

```
1 => 2
8 => 2
9 => 2
```

Edit: tucuxi asked: why not use the stream to print with too? You may do that of course, for shorter and yet simpler code:

```
        frequencies.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() == topFrequency)
                .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .forEach(n -> System.out.println("" + n + " => " + topFrequency));
```

What to choose depends on both requirements and taste. I was expecting that the OP would need to store the top frequency numbers, so I demonstrated how to do that, and just printed them to show the result. Also some hold the ideal that streams should be free from side effects, where I would consider printing to standard output a side effect. But use it if you like.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn’t read those three words properly. The code is yours for the project if you like, of course.

Comment: I'm not pro at advanced component of Java. So, I have asked :D

Answer (score 3):

This code is very inefficient and may run in `O(n^2)` at the worst case.

You can achieve your goal with a single for loop by building a `Map<Integer,Integer>` where the key is each unique number you encounter and the value is its frequency.

After you have the `Map`, it's trivial to find all the numbers having max frequency (just iterate over all the entries of the `Map`). The total running time will be `O(n)`.

```
int maxFreq = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Map<Integer,Integer> freqs = new HashMap<>();
for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
    int number = random.nextInt(n);
    data[i] = number;
    Integer freq = freqs.get(number);
    if (freq != null) {
        freq = freq + 1;
    } else {
        freq = 1;
    }
    freqs.put(number,freq);
    if (freq > maxFreq)
        maxFreq = freq;
}
for(Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : freqs.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue().equals(maxFreq)) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() +" => "+ maxFreq);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Java8 stream for it. In some cases you can even use parallel stream to improve performance. Here is how I would do that:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1, 8, 7, 8, 9, 2, 1, 9, 6, 4, 3, 5);
    //Here we have statistics of frequency for all numbers
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, Integer> statistics = integers.stream().distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), number -> Collections.frequency(integers, number)))
        .entrySet().stream().sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (o1, o2) -> o1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    //Calculate max frequency
    Integer maxFrequency = statistics.entrySet().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue).orElse(null);
    //Collect max frequent numbers to a map
    Map<Integer, Integer> topFrequentNumbers = statistics.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getValue().equals(maxFrequency))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    //Print
    topFrequentNumbers.forEach((number, frequency) -> System.out.println(number + " => " + frequency));
}
```

Output:

```
1 => 2
8 => 2
9 => 2
```

As I mentioned, you can play with parallel streams and extracting some pieces to improve performance.

Comment: much more complex than OleV's answer, which is also stream-based

Comment: @tucuxi, you're right. Mine was more complicated. I also like how it was done in OleV's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this to be the simplest optimal (`O(n)`, for this problem) answer. As in many other answers, it calculates frequency for all integers. Unlike others, it does not need a second pass to find the most frequent result, and in particular does not perform a sort-by-frequency, which is overkill if you only need "the most frequent". Also, short code is easier to debug.

```
   public static ArrayList<Integer> mostFrequent(int [] numbers) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> mostFrequent = new ArrayList<>();
        int greatestFrequency = 0;
        for (int n : numbers) {

            // build number -> frequency of number map
            int f = frequencies.getOrDefault(n, 0) + 1;
            frequencies.put(n, f);

            if (f > greatestFrequency) {
                // this number is more frequent than all others:
                //  it is now the sole, most frequent, number: no ties
                mostFrequent.clear();
                greatestFrequency = f;
            }
            if (f == greatestFrequency) {
                // this number is as frequent as the most frequent:
                //  add it to the list of numbers tied for this privilege
                mostFrequent.add(n);
            }
        }

        // print out the final list of numbers that are tied for "most frequent"
        for (int n : mostFrequent) {
            System.out.println(n + " => " + greatestFrequency);
        }
    }
```

Note that `null` is only returned for empty lists. Throwing an exception could also be valid. With little work, this code would accept any `Iterable<Number>`, but this would make it somewhat harder to understand. I doubt that the OP wants to use it in a production system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and this is similar to what I want "Small and optimized" but, I don't know how it works.

Comment: I have added comments. Broadly speaking, instead of looking at the frequencies at the end, it updates the "most frequent" title (and a list of ties for that title) on the go.

Comment: Just one flow of loop, Great